# Helm lookup always empty

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, helm3

While deploying a Kubernetes application, I want to check if a resource is already present. If so it shall not be rendered. To archive this behaviour the [lookup function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/) of helm is used. As it seems is always empty while deploying (no dry-run). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
    ---
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "ServiceAccount" "my-namespace" "my-sa") }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.environment }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels: 
    app:  {{ $.Chart.Name }}
    environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.environment }}@{{ .Values.gcpProjectId }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
{{- end }}
```

running the corresponding kubectl command return the expected service account

`kubectl get ServiceAccount my-sa -n my-namespace` lists the expected service account

helm version: 3.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you cannot use this if-statement to validate what you want.

the lookup function returns a list of objects that were found by your lookup. so, if you want to validate that there are no serviceaccounts with the properties you specified, you should check if the returned list is empty.

test something like

```
---
{{ if eq (len (lookup "v1" "ServiceAccount" "my-namespace" "my-sa")) 0 }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.environment }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels: 
    app:  {{ $.Chart.Name }}
    environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.environment }}@{{ .Values.gcpProjectId }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
{{- end }}
```

see: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function

Comment: According to the docs, a lookup with an object name returns a map, not a list (what the OP uses). If no name is provided, then it returns a list of objects.

Quoting from the docs [1]:

```
The lookup function can be used to look up resources in a running cluster. The synopsis of the lookup function is lookup apiVersion, kind, namespace, name -> resource or resource list.
```

[1] https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function