# Helm lookup() always empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using `Docker Desktop on Windows` and also created a basic helm chart which uses `nginx`

I am working on the `lookup()` function of Helm chart but it's **NOT working** as expected

**_helpers.tpl**

```
{{- define  "nginx-manual-test.testSecret" -}}
{{- if (lookup "v1" "Secret" "" "secrets") }}
{{- $maxValue := 10 }}
{{- printf "%s-%d" .Release.Name $maxValue | trunc 50 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- $maxValue := 20 }}
{{- printf "%s-%d" .Release.Name $maxValue | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

**Output of kubectl api-resources**

```
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
secrets                                        v1                                     true         Secret
```

Despite having the **required Secret** in the Cluster, `lookup()` functions executes `else block` **instead of** `if block`

I also looked into the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156026/helm-lookup-always-empty) but mine is not working

Am I doing anything wrong?  Any help or ideas?
where I am able to Secret

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with `lookup` here?  If you're just trying to check whether the cluster supports Secrets, you can probably just blindly assume you can (`.Capabilities.APIVersions` would tell you for sure, but the object hasn't changed for as long as I've been using Kubernetes).  IME you rarely if ever actually want `lookup` since it can lead to hard-to-test behavior and hard-to-verify dependencies.

Comment: @DavidMaze   In fact due to some reason lookup() is not working as expected.  I used ".Capabilities.APIVersion.Has" to check for API Resources and it worked fine.  Thank you for your suggestion.